# Need help figuring out how to solve using rules of inference

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that the argument form with premises (p ∧ t) → (r ∨ s), q →(u ∧ t), (u ∧ t), u → p, ¬s, and q with conclusion r.

i have everything set up in step and reason side i just don't know how to get started because the first premise is intimidating. I also have the tautology as [(p ∧ t) → (r ∨ s) ∧ (q →(u ∧ t)) ∧ (u ∧ t) ∧ (u → p) ∧ ¬s ∧ q] → r.

Comment: What have you tried?  What background do you have?  Where are you stuck?  Please edit the question to include this information.  Questions that don't show some independent effort to solve the problem tend not to be well received.

Comment: $(u\wedge t)$ is redundant given $q$ and $q\rightarrow (u\wedge t)$

Comment: I understand that, but how does that get me closer to r considering that q is not in the premise that r is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me break it down for you.

$u\wedge t $ means both are true.

Since $u$ is true so is $p$ since $u\rightarrow p$ is true. So $p,t$ are true.

Therefore, so is true $r\vee s$, as $p\wedge t$ is true.

Since $\sim s$ is true, $s$ is false, therefore $r$ is true.

Comment: Thank you i started working on that first comment you sent trying it out and i got the first two steps the same as you said so i must be doing it correctly now.

Comment: congrats. "practice makes perfect"

Comment: thank you again I've been trying to find videos on rules of inference it to explain it and I just wasn't getting anywhere but it makes sense now.

Comment: happy to help. this is my first semester teaching discrete and am looking to help with this stuff to better my teaching abilities

Comment: Yea the main thing was getting started once i got started everything started to fall into place, and the first premise being large made the whole thing intimidating.

Comment: reordering the premises can sometimes help, especially if with the same statement variables.

Comment: That makes sense thanks